# How to exclude traffic from specific ip on specific interface in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

On local machine I set counters for incoming and outgoing traffic in iptables to track how many bytes were used by user. But I need to exclude all traffic from "home server" (predefined ip address). How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your current rules to clarify exactly what to change?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new chain and redirect traffic that you want to count on this chain.

This post on StackExchange should help : [How to count packets coming from outside using iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/694840/how-to-count-packets-coming-from-outside-using-iptables)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Maybe there is another way to exclude such traffic?

Comment: Could you please add more precision here? 

I've some iptables entries running with none-original chain where I'm able to see only the desirable traffic.

I'm unfortunately not aware of iptables flag that will exclude counting on initial rules.

If you post you `iptables -S` result we should be able to advise further.